# stubbing factory_girl + rspec methods and attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, factory-bot

I'm using factory_girl + rspec on Rails 2-3-stable:

Test:

```
   context "test" do
      before(:each) do
        @profile.stub!(:lastfm_enabled?).and_return(true)
      end
      it "should be able to scrobble if true" do
        @profile.update_attribute(:lastfm_scrobbling, true)
        @profile.lastfm_scrobbling_enabled?.should be_true
      end
    end
```

Code:

```
def lastfm_scrobbling_enabled?
  lastfm_enabled? && lastfm_scrobbling
end
```

This simple test fails, plus the real lastfm_enabled? method gets called for real.

@profile is not a mock, it's created with factory_girl.

Initially I also stubbed the lastfm_scrobbling attribute, but I was thinking about the way factory_girl works and preferred to set it directly.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need stub the read_attribute method

```
  before(:each) do
    @profile.stub!(:read_attribute).with(:lastfm_enabled).and_return(true)
  end
```